# Optimization Methods Books

Tags: reference-request, optimization, book-recommendation, machine-learning, numerical-optimization

I'm interested in learning about optimization methods and how we can implement them in Machine Learning problems.  Which books shall I begin to read in order to understand classical and modern optimization methods deeply?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to optimisation theory these two books are the most recognizable:

1. [Convex Optimization, Stephen Boyd](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)
2. [Numerical Optimization, Jorge Nocedal Stephen J. Wright](http://www.apmath.spbu.ru/cnsa/pdf/monograf/Numerical_Optimization2006.pdf)

From my side I would strongly recommend a [Northwestern University Open Text Book on Process Optimization](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Main_Page) which is a concise summary/overview of optimisation techniques and examples of use, but is not as detailed and rigorous as the first two.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation